# Add datetime column with values based on another datetime column

Tags: sql, pandas, google-bigquery

I have a table:

```
|       date | x |
|------------+---|
| 2020-09-09 | 1 |
| 2020-09-09 | 2 |
| 2020-10-10 | 3 |
| 2020-10-10 | 4 |
| 2020-10-10 | 5 |
| 2020-11-11 | 6 |
| 2020-11-11 | 7 |
```

Using SQL language (BigQuery dialect) I need to add one column `date_today_max`, such that it copies all data from `date` column, but for records with the latest `date` (meaning `max(date)`) it will replace date with `current_date`:

```
|       date | date_today_max | x |
|------------+----------------+---|
| 2020-09-09 |     2020-09-09 | 1 |
| 2020-09-09 |     2020-09-09 | 2 |
| 2020-10-10 |     2020-10-10 | 3 |
| 2020-10-10 |     2020-10-10 | 4 |
| 2020-10-10 |     2020-10-10 | 5 |
| 2020-11-11 |     2020-11-15 | 6 |
| 2020-11-11 |     2020-11-15 | 7 |
```

with Python+Pandas I'd achieve similar with

```py
In [23]: from datetime import datetime

In [24]: import pandas as pd

In [25]: d = pd.date_range("2020-10-10","2020-10-15",freq="1d")

In [26]: df = pd.DataFrame(zip(d,[1,2,3,4,5,6]), columns=['date','x'])

In [27]: df['date_today_max'] = df['date'].replace(df['date'].max(),datetime.now().replace(hour=0,minute=0,second=0,microsecond=0))

In [28]: df
Out[28]:
        date  x date_today_max
0 2020-10-10  1     2020-10-10
1 2020-10-11  2     2020-10-11
2 2020-10-12  3     2020-10-12
3 2020-10-13  4     2020-10-13
4 2020-10-14  5     2020-10-14
5 2020-10-15  6     2020-11-15
```

but I have no clue how to tackle this with SQL. There is a `replace` function, but it only accepts strings as parameters.

Comment: Please explain the logic in English.  Code is handy if you wish, but human ideas are best expressed in human languages.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'd happily do so, however, I'm missing a whole set of vocabulary to properly describe these problems, even for such a basic problem like this. Maybe your book will help me change that :). Thank you for your help, your solution worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you simply want a `case` expression with a window function:

```
select date, x,
       (case when date = max(date) over ()
             then current_date else date
        end) as date_today_max
from t;
```